# ActiveMQ Artemis - Obtain list of available Addresses using JMS

Tags: java, jms, activemq-artemis

I recently had to switch from ActiveMQ 5.X to ActiveMQ Artemis for the project I'm working on.  I have a function that would read the available topics and populate a table in a MySQL database, but the function no longer works with the change in methodology in Artemis.

Basically, instead of getting the list of available Topics (aka mutlicast queues), I need to get a list of available addresses so that my consumer can connect and create a multicast queue for that address with the same name.

Here's why I need this functionality:

- User selects address name from ActiveMQ using a website (which reads from
  database)
- consumer connects to that address name and makes the queue
- Java consumer / producer updates database every second with available addresses for the website

Here is the previous code I have that worked with the previous ActiveMQ 5.X:

```
public class ActiveMQ {

    public ActiveMQ(String amq_url) throws JMSException, NamingException{
        ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(amq_url);      
        this.connection = (ActiveMQConnection) connectionFactory.createConnection();
        session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        connection.start();
    }

    public void useTopic(String topicName) throws JMSException{
        this.topic = session.createTopic(topicName);
        this.producer = session.createConsumer(topic);
    }

    
    public void readAvailableTopics() throws JMSException{ 
         
        Set<ActiveMQTopic> topics = connection.getDestinationSource().getTopics();
        System.out.println(topics.toString());
        return topics;
    }
```

The readAvailableTopics() method is the one in question.

I've tried .getTopics() and .getQueues() on both the consumer AND producer side and they both always return an empty set.  I cannot find any documentation for JMS in order to get the available addresses.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Management operations like this are not covered by the JMS specification so every broker implementation will have different ways of providing access. ActiveMQ Artemis is similar in many ways to ActiveMQ "Classic," but accessing management operations is different. That said, you *can* [use JMS to invoke management operations](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/management.html#using-management-message-api). You can list all the addresses using code like this:

```java
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.Queue;
import javax.jms.QueueConnection;
import javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.QueueRequestor;
import javax.jms.QueueSession;
import javax.jms.Session;
...
import org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.jms.ActiveMQJMSClient;
import org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.jms.management.JMSManagementHelper;
import org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.management.ResourceNames;
...

QueueSession session = connection.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
Queue managementQueue = ActiveMQJMSClient.createQueue("activemq.management");
QueueRequestor requestor = new QueueRequestor(session, managementQueue);
Message m = session.createMessage();
JMSManagementHelper.putOperationInvocation(m, ResourceNames.BROKER, "getAddressNames");
Message reply = requestor.request(m);
boolean success = JMSManagementHelper.hasOperationSucceeded(reply);
if (success) {
   Object[] addresses = (Object[]) JMSManagementHelper.getResult(reply);
   for (Object address : addresses) {
      System.out.println(address);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  I will give this a try tonight.

Comment: can you elaborate how you are declaring "requestor" in the above example?  Netbeans is also having me typecast from Message, to ClientMessage, and back again.  Sorry, I'm relatively new to ActiveMQ/JMS.

Comment: I updated the code with the necessary JMS imports, etc.

Comment: Thanks justin, Im getting an error with ```JMSManagementHelper.putOperationInvocation(m, ResourceNames.BROKER, "getAddressNames");```
Getting a ```javax.jms.JMSException: Cannot send a foreign message as a management message org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQMessage``` error.

Comment: The class `org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQMessage` is from the OpenWire JMS client implementation from ActiveMQ "Classic." You need to use the core JMS client implementation from ActiveMQ Artemis.

Comment: I think you're confusing interfaces and implementations. `JMSManagementHelper#putOperationInvocation` is expecting an object which _implements_ the `javax.jms.Message` interface. `org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQMessage` implements `javax.jms.Message` and so does, for example, `org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQMessage`. The former is from the OpenWire JMS client implementation from ActiveMQ "Classic" and the latter is from the core JMS client from ActiveMQ Artemis.

Comment: Thank you! i figured it out.  I still had the old activeMQ dependencies listed in my maven pom.xml file in addition to the artemis ones.  I got it working.  Thank you SOO much for the help!

Comment: You may not be using `org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQMessage` directly in your code, but you don't have to. That's the implementation of `javax.jms.Message` on your classpath.

Answer (score 0):

The ActiveMQ 5 client updates the lists of topics and queues through the [advisory messages](https://activemq.apache.org/advisory-message). Since ActiveMQ Artemis 2.18 the advisory messages support is disabled by default, see [ARTEMIS-3414](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-3414). To enable the advisory messages support add the supportAdvisory parameter to the acceptor, i.e.

```
<acceptor name="artemis">tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?protocols=OPENWIRE;supportAdvisory=true</acceptor>
```